# Parent/Child Update on Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, custom-list

I have a parent list (Contracts) with many child lists (Invoices, Companies, etc). The Parent:ID is a lookup on the child lists to relate them. I have figured out a way that when I update a people picker field on the parent it will update on the child, via workflow, however it only updates the first child.

How do I get it to cycle through and update all of the associated child items instead of stopping at the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You could provide some screenshots of the parent list、 child lists and the workflow for further assistance.

If you want to update all the associated child items, you should add multiple update list item actions separately.